# Does $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k s_k(t) $, where $s_k$ is the $k$-th Schauder function, converge unconditionally?

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

The family $\left\{h_k(\cdot)\right\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ of Haar functions are defined for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ as follows:
$$
\begin{gathered}
h_0(t):=1 \quad \text { for } 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\
h_1(t):=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
1 & \text { for } 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
-1 & \text { for } \frac{1}{2}<t \leq 1
\end{array}\right.
\end{gathered}
$$
If $2^n \leq k<2^{n+1}, n=1,2, \ldots$, we set
$$
h_k(t):=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
2^{n / 2} \text { for } \frac{k-2^n}{2^n} \leq t \leq \frac{k-2^n+1 / 2}{2^n} \\
-2^{n / 2} \text { for } \frac{k-2^n+1 / 2}{2^n}<t \leq \frac{k-2^n+1}{2^n} \\
0 \text { otherwise. }
\end{array}\right.
$$
For $k=0,1,2, \ldots$,
$$
s_k(t):=\int_0^t h_k(s) d s \quad(0 \leq t \leq 1)
$$
is the $k$-th Schauder function.

Let $\left\{a_k\right\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that
$$
\left|a_k\right|=O\left(k^\delta\right) \quad \text { as } k \rightarrow \infty
$$
for some $0 \leq \delta<1 / 2$. Then the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k s_k(t)
$$
converges uniformly for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

**Proof**. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Notice that for $2^n \leq k<2^{n+1}$, the functions $s_k(\cdot)$ have disjoint supports.
Set
$$
b_n:=\max _{2^n \leq k<2^{n+1}}\left|a_k\right| \leq C\left(2^{n+1}\right)^\delta
$$
Then for $0 \leq t \leq 1$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \leq C \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\left(2^{n+1}\right)^\delta 2^{-n / 2-1}<\varepsilon \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
for $m$ large enough, since $0 \leq \delta<1 / 2$. This concludes the proof.

I would like to know if the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k s_k(t)
$$
is unconditionally convergent. Remember that if $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_{\sigma(k)}$ is convergent for all permutations $\sigma$, we say that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k$ is unconditionally convergent. In that case, the limit is the same regardless of the order of summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $
\left|a_k\right|=O\left(k^\delta\right)$, there is a constant $D>0$ such that
$$ \left|a_k\right|< Dk^\delta\quad\text{for all } k\ge1. $$

For $n\ge1$, let $$u_n(t)=\sum_{2^n \le k<2^{n+1}}|a_ks_k(t)|\quad\text{for }t\in [0,1].$$
Since for $2^n\le k<2^{n+1}$, the functions $s_k(\cdot)$ have disjoint supports,

$$
u_n(t)<D\left(2^{n+1}\right)^\delta2^{-n/2-1}
$$

So$$\begin{aligned}
&\quad\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |a_k s_k(t)|\\
&\le |a_0| +|a_1|/2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n(t)\\
&<|a_0| +|a_1|/2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
D\left(2^{n+1}\right)^\delta2^{-n/2-1}\\
&=|a_0| +|a_1|/2+ 
\frac{D2^{2\delta-3/2}}{1-2^{-1/2+\delta}}.
\end{aligned}$$

The last expression is finite. Hence $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k s_k(t)$ converges unconditionally.